# What kind of glue for shower drain?

Tags: shower, drain, adhesive

I have a shower drain cover which is loose.  I don't have any leaks, but the plastic grate that covers the drain hole is loose and slides around.  What kind of glue should I use to keep this plastic in place without making it too permanent?

Here is the bottom of the cover and the hole I wish it would stay in for a long while:

[image: drain hole and cover upside down]

Comment: Silicone caulk.

Comment: It was probably intended to snap in, twist into a slot, or attach by some other non-adhesive means. Please post a brand, model, or photo for better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For drain covers with no screw holes and no option of screwing in itself we usually slap some plumber's putty on the bottom and smash it in.  With a screwdriver and a few tugs you can remove and reuse again but should keep it from moving.

Comment: I finally got this done and it is working great.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good idea not to glue or make the grate non-removable in case access to the drain is needed in the future. For a fast non-adhesive fix to keep the grate in-place wrap a rubber band around the grates edge.